# extend library class from non activity class

Tags: java, android, class, extends

I have a Main activity and one subclass called Indicator. Then I have a library Project with a class SessionIndicator which i want to extend with the Indicator class from the Main Project.

```
com.example
|_app
|  |_MainActivity
|  |_Indicator class
|
|_library project
   |_SessionIndicator class
```

Code (Main Acitivity, sub class):

```
package com.example.main;
public abstract class Indicator{}
```

Code Library Project:

```
package com.example.lib;
public SessionIndicator extends Indicator{}
```

The indicator class can not be found in the library project.

How can i get this working?
How to import the Indicator class into the Library project?

Comment: I believe your app depends on your library, not the other way. so you can get access from the app to the library classes, not vice versa

Comment: I don't think this is possible. For what you want you would have to create dependency to your main project in your library project, which would create cyclic dependency. One solution would be to import library's source code to the main project.

Comment: the library contains indicators for the panel in the main project which can be added dynamically. in the main project Indicator class i have the getters and setters for the indicators, so in the library class i want to build the custom indicator s based upon this class, or is it the wrong way to use a library for that? I want use it like modules.

Comment: @urgas9  the best answer so far, you can write it as answer then i can upvote, i will try to find another solution. Maybe like you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment:
I don't think this is possible. For what you want you would have to create dependency to your main project in your library project, which would create cyclic dependency. One solution would be to import library's source code to the main project.

If I understand your project structure right, you can only import classes to your main project from library and not vice-versa. I am sure you can avoid this scenario, one way is described above (ugly but quick fix), another would be to generate another library - your own - from your main project and then import it as dependency/library. I don't know exactly which technology are you using. But beware of cyclic dependencies in build tools (Gradle, Maven...)

Comment: If i put the indicator class in the library project and make a new independent library project can i extend its class with the indicator class from the projects library?

Comment: I think you can. The point is that you cannot extend a class from the main project in a library project.